# performances of distinct/group by

Tags: postgresql, performance, group-by, distinct, postgresql-10

I'm trying to select the most recent authors of messages in a room, using this (simplified) table:

```
             Table "public.message"
 Column  |  Type   | Nullable |               Default               
---------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id      | bigint  | not null | nextval('message_id_seq'::regclass)
 room    | integer | not null | 
 author  | integer | not null | 
 created | integer | not null | 
Indexes:
    "message_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "message_author_created_room" btree (author, created, room)
    "message_room_author_created" btree (room, author, created)
    "message_room_created" btree (room, created)
    "message_room_id" btree (room, id)
```

The problem is a query like this is slow:

```
select message.author as id, max(message.created) as mc from message
where room=12 group by message.author order by mc desc limit 50;
```

And here's the `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)`:

```
miaou=> explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select message.author as id, max(message.created) as mc from message
where room=12 group by message.author order by mc desc limit 50;
                                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=10627.14..10627.26 rows=50 width=8) (actual time=54.887..54.901 rows=50 loops=1)
   Output: author, (max(created))
   Buffers: shared hit=490
   ->  Sort  (cost=10627.14..10629.19 rows=820 width=8) (actual time=54.885..54.891 rows=50 loops=1)
         Output: author, (max(created))
         Sort Key: (max(message.created)) DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 29kB
         Buffers: shared hit=490
         ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1000.46..10599.90 rows=820 width=8) (actual time=14.019..54.788 rows=160 loops=1)
               Output: author, max(created)
               Group Key: message.author
               Buffers: shared hit=490
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.46..10583.50 rows=1640 width=8) (actual time=14.007..54.636 rows=248 loops=1)
                     Output: author, (PARTIAL max(created))
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     Buffers: shared hit=490
                     ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=0.43..9394.18 rows=820 width=8) (actual time=3.439..34.733 rows=83 loops=3)
                           Output: author, PARTIAL max(created)
                           Group Key: message.author
                           Buffers: shared hit=2989
                           Worker 0: actual time=0.297..49.593 rows=116 loops=1
                             Buffers: shared hit=1550
                           Worker 1: actual time=6.624..40.612 rows=60 loops=1
                             Buffers: shared hit=949
                           ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using message_room_author_created on public.message  (cost=0.43..8904.09 rows=96377 width=8) (actual time=0.030..20.067 rows=73907 loops=3)
                                 Output: author, created
                                 Index Cond: (message.room = 12)
                                 Heap Fetches: 139
                                 Buffers: shared hit=2989
                                 Worker 0: actual time=0.035..28.355 rows=109834 loops=1
                                   Buffers: shared hit=1550
                                 Worker 1: actual time=0.030..23.723 rows=79112 loops=1
                                   Buffers: shared hit=949
 Planning time: 0.211 ms
 Execution time: 57.071 ms
```

I'd like to know how to make that faster, the real important goal being to get the N most recent authors. Is there a faster way to query that information?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the select list regardless of any useless parentheses around the columns. `distinct (author)` is **exactly** the same thing as `distinct author`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that poinr about `distinct` (I was playing with several alternatives, like `count` in order to try making sense of the durations).

Comment: "*I'm puzzled as to why my message_room_author_created index cannot be used*" - the execution plan clearly shows that Postgres **is** using that index: `Parallel Index Only Scan using message_room_author_created`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had only tried the `explain analyze` before, I didn't even know the `verbose` parameter... I'll edit to remove that dumb sentence

Comment: 57 ms execution time doesn't look slow at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(author) from message where room=12;
```

Because author can not be null just do `SELECT count(*)`. Doing so may result in this being an index-only scan on either `message_room_created` or `message_room_id`. If you need the unique authors, which you don't have you'll have to use `count( DISTINCT author )`.

Also this being planned as a parallel query. That's relatively new functionality. You may want to try `SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0` to disable parallel query functionality and reposting the results.

Either way

> this one is slow (same duration, about **45ms**)

If you've got millions rows an index scan and heap fetches, it's not really fair to call 45ms "slow."

Comment: The goal is to get the most recent authors, I gave that one query with the count as an example

Comment: I tried changing the number of parallel workers, it's much faster with 8 (as was default). Thanks for bringing my attention to that, though.

Comment: At this point you don't even have a single `seq scan` in your query and your using a very compound index `message_room_author_created`. Grab a beer that query is as good as it's getting. If you need faster, move to materialized views.